# Run-time error '462' - Excel automation fails second time code runs

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, runtime-error

I'm building a word document from excel. When I insert a image in the document and re-size it I get a run time error. I only happens when I run it a second time.

```
Dim PreparedSigPath As String
Dim sWdth, sHght As Single

'file paths for image
PreparedSigPath = Range("Prepared_Sig").Value

'insert and re-size image
Set PreparedSig = docreport.Bookmarks("PREPARED_SIG").Range.InlineShapes _
    .AddPicture(PreparedSigPath)
With PreparedSig
    sWdth = .Width
    sHght = .Height
    'size to max width
    .Width = InchesToPoints(2.125)
    .Height = sHght * .Width / sWdth
    'size to max height if needed
    If .Height > InchesToPoints(0.625) Then
        .Height = InchesToPoints(0.625)
        .Width = sWdth * .Height / sHght
    End If
End With
```

The code breaks at `.Width = InchesToPoints(2.125)`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`.Width = Application.InchesToPoints(2.125)`.